# Show all markers placed at 5km distance from route

Tags: sql, database, android-studio, filter, google-maps-markers

In my application I show the route between point A to point B.

```
final PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polyOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.accent_color));
polyOptions.width(20);
polyOptions.addAll(currentRoute.getPoints());
```

In currentRoute.getPoints I have all LatLng used to draw route on map. I extract all points that have 5km distance between them into a ListArray named points.

Now I want to populate along this route with locations from my database. I need to display all locations from my database that are on route or near it on 5km limit (on both sides of route).

For that I need to go to database and filter the records to find all locations that are in 5km range. I don't know how to implement WHERE request for location_latitude and location_longitude  to can get all records that are on 5km range to reference location.

My current SQL is:

```
query = "SELECT location_id, location_name, " +
                "location_address, location_image, " +
                "location_latitude, location_longitude, " +
                "c.category_marker, l.category_id " +
                "FROM tbl_categories c, tbl_locations l " +
                "WHERE l.category_id " + " = " + categ + " AND l.category_id = c.category_id AND " +
                "location_county " + " =  \"" + county + "\"";
```

Any suggestion how to filter faster my database (sql query) to find all locations near route?

Comment: A lot (all?) information about your database is missing. How would anybody suggest a filter that will do it faster, faster than what?

Comment: In currentRoute.getPoints I have all LatLng used to draw route on map. I extract all points that have 5km distance between. Then I need to go to database and filter records to find all locations that are in 5km range. I don't know how to implement WHERE request as to get all records that are on 5km range to reference location.

Comment: Calculate distance, and compare this, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=764bfb439e516a9ad90131b21f38e056)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gone to this way:

```
 where_query = new StringBuilder();
        for (i = 0; i <= points.size()-1 ; i ++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                where_query.append(" AND ((location_latitude between ").append(points.get(i).latitude - 0.1).append(" AND ").append(points.get(i).latitude + 0.1).append(" AND location_longitude between ").append(points.get(i).longitude - 0.1).append(" AND ").append(points.get(i).longitude + 0.1).append(")");
            } else {
                if (i < points.size() - 1) {
                    where_query.append(" OR (location_latitude between ").append(points.get(i).latitude - 0.1).append(" AND ").append(points.get(i).latitude + 0.1).append(" AND location_longitude between ").append(points.get(i).longitude - 0.1).append(" AND ").append(points.get(i).longitude + 0.1).append(")");
                } else {
                    where_query.append(" OR (location_latitude between ").append(points.get(i).latitude - 0.1).append(" AND ").append(points.get(i).latitude + 0.1).append(" AND location_longitude between ").append(points.get(i).longitude - 0.1).append(" AND ").append(points.get(i).longitude + 0.1).append("))");
                }
            }
        }
```

Waiting suggestions!